# Image convolution using matrix(Edge detection)

Tags: c, image, convolution

I am working on image convolution. And i want to give it a edge mask effect.
When it is convoluted, the image should be close to black but my image is closer to gray. if you see my code and work it with your [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m7Sm.png) you'll see what i am talking about.

### Source file

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include "BMPImage.h"

RGB getPixelColor(
        const RGB* rgb_array,
        const int res_x,
        const int res_y,
        int i,
        int j)
{
    if (i < 0)
        i += res_x;

    if (j < 0)
        j += res_y;

    i = i%res_x;
    j = j%res_y;

    const int ix = i + res_x*j;

    assert(ix >= 0);
    assert(ix < res_x * res_y);

    return rgb_array[ix];
}

void main()
{
    int res_x, res_y;

    RGB* rgb_array = NULL;

    readBMP24("my_pic.bmp", &res_x, &res_y, &rgb_array);

    RGB* rgb_temp = (RGB*)malloc(sizeof(RGB)*res_x*res_y);

    float conv_mat[3][3] = { -1,-1,-1,
                            -1,8,-1,
                            -1,-1,-1 };

    for (int j = 0; j < res_y; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < res_x; i++)
        {
            RGB color_temp = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

            for(int sub_j = 0; sub_j < 3; sub_j++)
            {
                for (int sub_i = 0; sub_i <3; sub_i++)
                {

                    RGB color_neighbor = getPixelColor(
                            rgb_array,
                            res_x,
                            res_y,
                            i + sub_i - 1,
                            j + sub_j - 1);

                    color_neighbor.red_ *= conv_mat[sub_i][sub_j];
                    color_neighbor.green_ *= conv_mat[sub_i][sub_j];
                    color_neighbor.blue_ *= conv_mat[sub_i][sub_j];

                    color_temp.red_ += color_neighbor.red_;
                    color_temp.green_ += color_neighbor.green_;
                    color_temp.blue_ += color_neighbor.blue_;
                }
                rgb_temp[i + res_x * j] = color_temp;

            }

            //rgb_temp[i + res_x * j] = getPixelColor(
            //      rgb_array, res_x, res_y, i, j);             
        }
    }

    writeBMP24("changed_output.bmp", res_x, res_y, rgb_temp);

    free(rgb_array);
    free(rgb_temp);
}
```

### Source file

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    float red_;
    float blue_;
    float green_;
}RGB;

struct BMPHeader
{
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

    char file_type_[2];        // "BM"
    int file_size_;            // Size of file in bytes
    int reserved_;             // set to 0
    int offBits_;              // Byte offset to actual bitmap data
                               //   (= 54)
    int header_size_;          // Size of BITMAPINFOHEADER,
                               //   in bytes (= 40)
    int width_;                // Width of image, in pixels
    int height_;               // Height of images, in pixels
    short planes_;             // Number of planes in target device (set to 1)
    short bit_count_;          // Bits per pixel (24 in this case)
    int compression_;          // Type of compression
                               //   (0 if no compression)
    int size_image_;           // Image size, in bytes
                               //   (0 if no compression)
    int pixel_per_meter_x_;    // Horizontal resolution of the image
                               //   (pixel per meter)
    int pixel_per_meter_y_;    // Vertical resolution of the image
                               //   (pixel per meter)
    int num_color_palette_;    // Number of colors in the color table
                               //   (if 0, use maximum allowed by
                               //   biBitCount)
    int num_color_important_;  // Number of important colors.
                               //   If 0, all colors are important
};

const bool writeBMP24(const char *filename,
        const int x_res,
        const int y_res,
        RGB* rgb_array)
{
    int i, j, ipos;
    int bytesPerLine;
    unsigned char *buffer;

    FILE *file;
    struct BMPHeader header;

    int width = x_res;
    int height = y_res;

    // The length of each line must be a multiple of 4 bytes
    bytesPerLine = (3 * (width + 1) / 4) * 4;

    strcpy(header.file_type_, "BM");

    header.offBits_ = 54;
    header.file_size_ = header.offBits_ + bytesPerLine * height;
    header.reserved_ = 0;
    header.header_size_ = 40;
    header.width_ = width;
    header.height_ = height;
    header.planes_ = 1;
    header.bit_count_ = 24;
    header.compression_ = 0;
    header.size_image_ = bytesPerLine * height;
    header.pixel_per_meter_x_ = 0;
    header.pixel_per_meter_y_ = 0;
    header.num_color_palette_ = 0;
    header.num_color_important_ = 0;

    file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (file == NULL)
        return(0);

    fwrite(&header.file_type_, 2, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.file_size_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.reserved_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.offBits_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.header_size_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.width_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.height_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.planes_, 2, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.bit_count_, 2, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.compression_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.size_image_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.pixel_per_meter_x_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.pixel_per_meter_y_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.num_color_palette_, 4, 1, file);
    fwrite(&header.num_color_important_, 4, 1, file);

    buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(bytesPerLine);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't allocate memory for BMP file.\n");
        return false;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            ipos = 3 * (width * i + j);
            buffer[3 * j]     = (unsigned char)rgb_array[
                    (j + i * x_res)].blue_; // blue

            buffer[3 * j + 1] = (unsigned char)rgb_array[
                    (j + i * x_res)].green_; // green

            buffer[3 * j + 2] = (unsigned char)rgb_array[
                    (j + i * x_res)].red_;  // red
        }

        fwrite(buffer, bytesPerLine, 1, file);
    }

    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);

    return true;
}

const bool readBMP24(
    const char* imagepath,
    int* res_x_,
    int* res_y_,
    RGB** rgb_array)
{
    printf("Reading image %s\n", imagepath);

    // Data read from the header of the BMP file
    unsigned char header[54];
    unsigned int dataPos;
    unsigned int imageSize;
    unsigned int width, height;

    // Open the file
    FILE * file = fopen(imagepath, "rb");
    if (!file) {
        printf("%s could not be opened."
            " Are you in the right directory?"
            " Don't forget to read the FAQ !\n",
            imagepath);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    // Read the header, i.e. the 54 first bytes

    // If less than 54 bytes are read, problem
    if (fread(header, 1, 54, file) != 54) {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return false;
    }
    // A BMP files always begins with "BM"
    if (header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M') {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure this is a 24bpp file
    if (*(int*)&(header[0x1E]) != 0) {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return false;
    }
    if (*(int*)&(header[0x1C]) != 24) {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return false;
    }

    // Read the information about the image
    dataPos = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
    imageSize = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);
    width = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);
    height = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);

    // Some BMP files are mis-formatted, guess missing information
    //  if (imageSize == 0)    imageSize = width*height*3;
    // 3 : one byte for each Red, Green and Blue component

    if (dataPos == 0)
        dataPos = 54; // The BMP header is done that way

    *res_x_ = width;
    *res_y_ = height;

    int scanline_byte = *res_x_ * 3;
    int padding = 0;

    while ((scanline_byte + padding) % 4 != 0)
        padding++;

    int psb = scanline_byte + padding; // padded scanline byte
    imageSize = psb*height;

    // Read the actual data from the file into the buffer
    unsigned char* image_buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(
        sizeof(unsigned char)*imageSize);
    fread(image_buf, 1, imageSize, file);

    // Create a buffer
//      data_.initialize(0, 0, width, height, false);

    *rgb_array = (RGB*)malloc(sizeof(RGB)*(width * height ));

    long buf_pos = 0;
    long new_pos = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3 * width; x += 3)
        {
            new_pos = y*width + x / 3;
            buf_pos = y*psb + x;

            (*rgb_array)[new_pos].red_ =
                (float)image_buf[buf_pos + 2];
            (*rgb_array)[new_pos ].green_ =
                (float)image_buf[buf_pos + 1];
            (*rgb_array)[new_pos].blue_ =
                (float)image_buf[buf_pos + 0];
        }
    }

    // Everything is in memory now, the file wan be closed
    fclose(file);

    free(image_buf);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I reformatted the code to be readable without horizontal scrolling and separated files more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Good edge detection will be a multi step process:

1) Preprocess with a low pass filter to reduce noise (a small kernel Gaussian or Median Blur will do the trick)

2) Apply your matrix.

3) Apply a threshold to your matrix results.

See images below:

[image: Original image]
Original

[image: bad result]
Result of your matrix.

[image: low pass filter]
Original with low pass filter (Median Blur)

[image: good result]
Your matrix on low pass filtered image

[image: final image]
Your matrix on low pass filtered image with threshold applied.